# extract flutter source code from release apk

Tags: flutter, apk, extract, release, decompiler

Actually I have lost my source code to my app and what I am left with is release apk. I come across some answers of extracting source code from debug apk. But I am afraid that I don't have debug apk.

So is there any way to get source code or have I lost it totally?

Thanks in advance for answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard, but not impossible to extract source code from a Release apk, mostly reverse engineering.

There are some projects / blogs talking about this:

- https://rloura.wordpress.com/2020/12/04/reversing-flutter-for-android-wip/
- https://github.com/rscloura/Doldrums
- https://medium.com/@rondalal54/reverse-engineering-flutter-apps-5d620bb105c0

If you're looking for only a part of the code, try binary instrumentation (Frida)

Answer (score 0):

You can't export the source code from apk

Comment: So basically I have lost my source code. Right??

Comment: Yes, unfortunately.